# ffmpeg: concatenation images and videos

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to  combine files img1.png and video1.ts into a single movie. Everything works correct except audio: if first file in the movie is img1.png - there is no audio for video.ts. If first file is video1.ts - everything works as expected.

What I do:

1) create a video file fom img1.png:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img1.png -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p img.ts
```

2) concatenation:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:img.ts|video1.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc res.mp4
```

What should I do to save audio for video1.ts ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a dummy audio stream with the same properties as the audio stream in the video file.

So, if the main audio is AAC, stereo, 44100 Hz, you would use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img1.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -t 30 img.ts
```